# Can detail be short?

Tags: word-request

At times, I am reluctant to use the word 'detail' simply because I ***actually*** don't want any detail.

Say, I just need dates of account opening and closure. That's it! How do I express it?

> You just need some _________ like dates of your account 
>  Sir, before I proceed, I need few ________ about yourself. Your name, and age. 
>  Lost phone? Okay, tell me _________ like which company it was of and what was the IMEI number?

Now, in above all blanks the word ***'things'*** works perfectly. But calling those all things 'thing' seems down to me!

On the other hand, 'details' means more, much...in content. Asking just two stuff or *things* is asking for the details? I'm not sure.

Is there any word that can replace *detail* if the required *thing* is NOT actually in detail but just one or two in number.

**Note:** I could think of using the word 'brief,' but as in the dictionaries, it does not fit here. [In fact, to my surprise, brief, at times, is detailing!](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brief)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **detail** *noun*
>   1 An individual feature, fact, or item.
>   ‘we shall consider every detail of the Bill’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/detail)

*Detail* can be thought of as an antonym of *gestalt* or perhaps *summary*.

Think of a beach. The 'whole' (breeze, sound of water, people playing, sand, waves, etc) would be the gestalt; 'pleasant beach' might be a summary. But an individual shell would be **a** detail.

In your examples, you're looking for *some* details - perhaps just the name and age, or just the dates. **It's fine to use the word "detail" or even the plural "details" in that context.** It's not asking for a full download of information.

The 'full download of information' sense comes with the phrase "**in** detail" or "go into detail":

> **go into detail** *phrase*
>   Give a full account of something.
>   ‘It is full colour and goes into detail on all aspects.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/detail)
>
> **in detail** *phrase*
>   As regards every feature or aspect; fully.
>   ‘we will have to examine the proposals in detail’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/detail)

Answer (score 0):

We might explain that, probably for procedural reasons, we need to collect specific information.

> Sir, before I proceed, I need few a specific details about you. First, your name, and age.

The use of **specific** helps to explain that we're not seeking exhaustive details but we are collecting precise information.